# Pass data from one html page to another html page in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
var mainApp=angular.module('myMainApp',['ngRoute']);
mainApp.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/showData',{
    templateUrl:'C:/Users/Lala/Desktop/angularjs_lala/PassDatatoAnotherSecondPage.html',
    controller:'MainPageController'
    }).

     otherwise({
    redirectTo: 'file:///C:/Users/Lala/Desktop/angularjs_lala/PassDatatoAnotherPage.html'
  });
  }]);

        mainApp.controller('MainPageController',['$scope',function($scope){         

        console.log("In controller");

        $scope.SubmitData=function(user){

            console.log("In function");
            $scope.userData={
                  Fname:user.name,
                  Lname:user.surname,
                  Mobno:user.Mobno,
                  City:user.city
            };
            console.log($scope.userData);
            //$state.go('file:///CC:/Users/Lala/Desktop/angularjs_lala/SubmitPassedData.html');
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: where is data you want pass ? You should use services for it

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/43700447/4116300

Answer (score 0):

You can do pass data in multiple ways.

1. localStorage of the browser
2. URL parameters
3. Server-side session
4. Cookies, outdated and inefficient nowadays.

You can refer below link for detail.

[How to pass data from one html page to another in angularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307289/how-to-pass-data-from-one-html-page-to-another-in-angularjs)